# JSTree show div when mouseover on tag "li"

Tags: jquery, jstree

Hi I have problem with JSTree I need show some divs when I hover some "li" or "ul" in JStree. 

Problem is - If I open all of children of "ul", then on hover I see what I want (= 3 colored divs), but when I collapse parent div, with his children, and after that open him then hover not work no more. (Parent Div 1)
If I have all childer of div closed then hover not work. (Parent Div 2)

JS:

```
$(function () {
  // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
  $('#jstree').jstree({
    "core" : {
      "check_callback" : true
    },
    "plugins" : [ "dnd" ]
  });
  // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
  $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.selected);
  });
  // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
    $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
    $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
  });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( '.jstree-node' ).mouseenter(function() { 
      $( ".ovladaci_prvky_uzlu" ).stop( true, true ).hide();
      $( this ).find(".ovladaci_prvky_uzlu").stop( true, true ).show();
    }).mouseleave(function() { 
      $( ".ovladaci_prvky_uzlu" ).stop( true, true ).hide();
    });

});
```

JSFiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/4s28w3pr/

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".ovladaci_prvky_uzlu").stop(true, true).hide();
            $(this).find(".ovladaci_prvky_uzlu").stop(true, true).show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(".ovladaci_prvky_uzlu").stop(true, true).hide();
        }
    }, '.jstree-node');
});
```

Hope this works. Thanks

Comment: @SevereTorture , i think there is bit isssues , like when mouse enter on parent node, then coloring appears for all the child nodes

this happenes when u start from bottom(leaf) node

Comment: If node(parent) has three childrens , if mouse enter on parent(node) then code is displaying colors for all the child nodes ..

so in order to resolve this issue , i made small change on code

inside mouseenter function

$(this).find(".ovladaci_prvky_uzlu").first().stop(true, true).show();